# Accessing json string using java code

Tags: java, json

I had following json format :

```
[
 { "Otype" : "win"},
 { "Otype" : "win"},
 { },
 { },
 { "Otype" : " win 7"},
 { "Otype" : " Linux"}
]
```

for accessing Otype I write java code as below:

```
while(cur.hasNext() && !isStopped()) {
    String json = cur.next().toString(); 
    JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(json);
    System.out.print(jObject.getString("Otype"));
}//end of while
```

So above print statement print only following results:

```
win
win
```

but not print:

```
{ "Otype" : " win 7"}
{ "Otype" : " Linux"}
```

I think it may be first white space in value field that's why it not print above two key so I changed in print statement as below:

```
System.out.print(jObject.getString("Otype").trim());
```

but still not work :( .

How I can access all above json value using java code?

Comment: include the code u used to initialize the cur object as well..

Comment: according to http://jsonlint.com/ this is not valid json.

Comment: I guess, the empty objects (`{ }`) will cause a problem when you try to access the `Otype` field. Did the code throw an exception?

Comment: Hi by mistake I write wrong json format but now I changed json format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my solution. I changed my code as below:

```
while(cur.hasNext() && !isStopped()) {
String json = cur.next().toString(); 
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(json);
if(jObject.has("Otype")){
       System.out.print(jObject.getString("Otype"));
   }//end of if
}//end of while
```

Comment: I am wondering how you get an iterator out of your given JSON String?

Comment: Hi I read mongo data using java code so before while I was write my query and set cur as DBCursor so in while it iterates all my json data  .

Answer (score 0):

use `toString()` like this

```
System.out.print(jObject.toString());
```

Comment: If I print above then it shows me all json formatted string, I just wanted to access values of given key.

Comment: try this, 
    System.out.print("{ \"Otype\" : \""+jObject.getString("Otype")+"\"}");